# How to get output to not write more SQL CASES using select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below xyz table data

```
id    ADivision     BDivision   CDivision     DDivision  EDivision     FDivision
 1       0              1           0           0            1           0
 2       1              1           0           0            1           1
```

I want output like below

```
 id    Divisions
 1     B-E
 2     A-B-E-F
```

I tried by using switch case but need to write more cases

any other ways to get output

Comment: What does your current query look like? To be clear, are you looking for a shorter and/or more flexible way to achieve your output?

Comment: A `CASE` or `IIF` is what you want here, if I am honest.

Comment: i know sql CASE  WHEN statement any other way to achieve shorter way yes. @Isolated

Comment: i want to show divisions in one field like above output. @Larnu

Comment: So `CONCAT`enate the outputs, @mazharkhan .

Comment: yes thanks to all for support. @Larnu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function is your friend here:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    CONCAT_WS('-', CASE WHEN ADivision = 1 THEN 'A' END,
                   CASE WHEN BDivision = 1 THEN 'B' END,
                   CASE WHEN CDivision = 1 THEN 'C' END,
                   CASE WHEN DDivision = 1 THEN 'D' END,
                   CASE WHEN EDivision = 1 THEN 'E' END,
                   CASE WHEN FDivision = 1 THEN 'F' END) AS Divisions
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```

Here is a workaround for earlier versions of SQL Server which might not support `CONCAT_WS()`:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    STUFF(
        COALESCE('-' + CASE WHEN ADivision = 1 THEN 'A' END, '') +
        COALESCE('-' + CASE WHEN BDivision = 1 THEN 'B' END, '') +
        COALESCE('-' + CASE WHEN CDivision = 1 THEN 'C' END, '') +
        COALESCE('-' + CASE WHEN DDivision = 1 THEN 'D' END, '') +
        COALESCE('-' + CASE WHEN EDivision = 1 THEN 'E' END, '') +
        COALESCE('-' + CASE WHEN FDivision = 1 THEN 'F' END, '')
        1, 2, '') AS Divisions
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Great logic thanks you are the man. @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: @mazharkhan Have a look at the updated answer above.

Comment: The purpose of `STUFF()` is to remove any possible leading `-`.